# OOP Pattern - handle methods that are extremely similar

Tags: java, oop

I have some methods that are super similar except for 1 line in each method. I'm trying to avoid duplicated code and apply good practices in my code but I'm no OOP expert. Both methods are identical except for for 1 call:

As example:

classa.java

```
    public static void updateTable() throws Exception {
        List<T> newSchema = AvroToHive.generateSchema(...);
        ...
    }
```

classb.java

```
    public static void updateTable() throws Exception {
        List<T> newSchema = AWSGlue.generateSchema(...);
        ...
    }
```

I would like to move the method `updateTable()` to another common class and avoid similar methods accross my project.

What is the right approach to avoid it? Should I write an interface like "Metastore" with the method `generateSchema`, implement it into classes AvroToHive/AWSGlue and pass it as parameter like:

```
    public static void updateTable(Metastore metastore) throws Exception {
        List<T> newSchema = metastore.generateSchema(...);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Who owns the table?

Comment: If classA and classB don't own a table, then maybe some sort of table manager makes sense, which will take care of the updateTable. 

The idea of passing in the Metastore seems like good design to me. It looks like dependency injection to me, but usually, with all the examples of dependency injection I've seen, it would involve storing the Metastore object. 

I think your design will be good like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an `interface` their common parent as follows:

```
interface Common {
    void generateSchema();
}

class AvroToHive implements Common {
    public void generateSchema() {
        System.out.println("In AvroToHive");
    }
}

class AWSGlue implements Common {
    public void generateSchema() {
        System.out.println("In AWSGlue");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Common obj1 = new AvroToHive();
        Common obj2 = new AWSGlue();
        updateTable(obj1);
        updateTable(obj2);
    }

    public static void updateTable(Common obj) {
        obj.generateSchema();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
In AvroToHive
In AWSGlue
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to implementing it would be to use a Functional Interface.

**AvroToHive Example:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AvroToHive {

  public static List<String> generateSchema() {
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("Hello");
    return values;
  }

}
```

**AWSGlue Example:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AWSGlue {

  public static List<Integer> generateSchema() {
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(10);
    return values;
  }

}
```

**Functional Interface Example:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class FuncInterExample {

  @FunctionalInterface
  interface ListSupplier<T> {
    List<T> generateSchema();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    updateTable(AvroToHive::generateSchema);
    updateTable(AWSGlue::generateSchema);
  }

  public static <T> void updateTable(ListSupplier<T> obj) {
    List<T> list = obj.generateSchema();
    for(T item : list) {
      System.out.println(item);
    }
  }

}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Hello
10
```